# Creating a binary file without .exe from python script

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to create a binary from python script. I tried pyinstaller, py2exe and they create a binary with .exe. Is there a way to create binary without .exe extensions in Windows ?

I am trying to create a game like minesweeper and don't like the .exe extension at the end, I just want an icon with game_name

Comment: You could always just delete the .exe extension :) What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if you remove the .exe extension you won't be able to run it anymore. WINL (Windows is not Linux :))

Comment: What are you intending to do by creating a binary without .exe on windows? Edit the question and explain about it. So that it helps others to understand and give the answer.

Comment: But minesweeper has a `.exe` extension. That's how it works on windows. Most files have extensions. Why do you need to be different? If you want just an icon you need to create a shortcut.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I was aware of that, hence my second statement.

Comment: @PeterWood I know minesweeper has .exe extension and I dont like it, hence wondering if there is a way to create the executable without .exe

Comment: What extension would you like? You can configure windows to open files with other extensions in particular ways. Having no extension, windows wouldn't know what to do with it, whether it was just data or executable (I know executables *are* data, but you understand the distinction the operating system has to make.) Is this data to be opened by another application, or is it data to execute as a process. Windows determines this using file extensions.

Comment: Run `set PathExt=.;;%PathExt%` to temporarily allow cmd and PowerShell to run files that lack an extension. That's all you need since they try `CreateProcess` first. Change `PathExt` permanently if you like. Explorer looks for the registered file association. To support that, in an elevated command prompt run `assoc .=ExeFile`. Now Explorer handles such files as binaries, i.e. it runs them directly via `CreateProcess`. It could be associated instead with a smart shebang processor -- something like Python's py launcher, except have it try `CreateProcess` first and then look for a shebang.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, that's not true. You can always run it directly via `CreateProcess`. Dealing with the constraints imposed by common Windows shells is another issue, which I addressed in my previous comment.

Comment: @eryksun I trust what you're saying since you know a lot about `CreateProcess`. But that's not practical of course. You still need some .exe at some point to be run by the user.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you mean a shell like cmd.exe, right? Just run `set PathExt=.;;%PathExt%` in a command prompt, and you'll be able to run a file that doesn't have an extension. Explorer requires a bit more magic. You have to associate the "." extension (i.e. files without an extension) with the `ExeFile` ProgId, which has a command template of `"%1" %*`, in which `%1` is the target file and `%*` is the rest of the command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of the extension, but you can hide it:

In Windows Explorer:

```
Organize => Folder and Search Options => View => Hide extensions for known file types
```

This will hide the .exe extension. As has been noted by others, Windows needs the extension to know what to do with the file, so the .exe is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut to your binary `.exe` file.

Right click on the binary and select `Create shortcut`.

You can then rename the shortcut to not include the `.exe` part of the filename.

It automatically picks up the icon from the `.exe` file, or you can choose a different icon from the shortcut properties.